# how to send CTRL+D keystroke using subprocess python

Tags: python, subprocess

I need to simulate CTRL+D keystroke to the process window

I am using subprocess python , but unable find any keystroke

```
p = subprocess.Popen('program1', stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,encoding='utf8',shell=True)
```

`p.stdin.write('')`-> i need to give control +D command

Comment: Just close (your end of) the pipe.

Comment: p.stdin.close()